# How to display pagination and categories correctly in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, notion-api

This is my index page. How can I correctly filtering my articles?
const filteredArticles = filterArticles(articles, selectedTag); > These code is my category filtering function.

const paginatePosts = paginate(articles, currentPage, pageSize, selectedTag); > Right out there is my article pagination section.

And then I get articles here  :

How can I execute both filteredArticles, paginatePosts in all my articles ?

```
import { convertToArticleList, getAllArticles } from "utils/notion";
import { Layout } from "layouts/Layout";
import HeroHeader from "components/HeroHeader";
import Container from "components/Container";
import { useState } from "react";
import ArticleList from "components/ArticleList";
import { filterArticles } from "utils/filterArticles";
import Category from "components/Category";
import Carousel from "components/Carousel";
import ArticleCard from "components/ArticleCard";
import Image from "next/image";
import BlogPagination from "components/Pagination";

import card1 from "../public/card1.svg";
import card2 from "../public/card2.svg";
import card3 from "../public/card3.svg";
import card4 from "../public/card4.svg";
import { paginate } from "utils/paginate";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Index({ articles, categories }) {
  const [selectedTag, setSelectedTag] = useState<string>(null);
  const filteredArticles = filterArticles(articles, selectedTag);
  const articleItems = [
    <Image className="h-full w-full" src={card1} alt="teste" />,
    <Image className="h-full w-full" src={card2} alt="teste" />,
    <Image className="h-full w-full" src={card3} alt="teste" />,
    <Image className="h-full w-full" src={card4} alt="teste" />,
    <Image className="h-full w-full" src={card1} alt="teste" />,
  ];

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const pageSize = 6;
  const router = useRouter();
  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
    router.push(`?page=${page}`, undefined, { shallow: true });
  };

  const paginatePosts = paginate(articles, currentPage, pageSize, selectedTag);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <HeroHeader />
      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4 pt-8  dark:bg-slate-900 ">
        {categories.map((tag) => (
          <Category
            tag={tag}
            key={tag}
            selectedTag={selectedTag}
            setSelectedTag={setSelectedTag}
            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Container>
        <div>
          <div className="my-8 text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 ">
            {!selectedTag ? "Сүүлд нийтэлсэн" : `${selectedTag}`}
          </div>
          <ArticleList articles={paginatePosts} />
          <BlogPagination
            items={articles.length}
            pageSize={pageSize}
            currentPage={currentPage}
            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
          />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const data = await getAllArticles(process.env.BLOG_DATABASE_ID);

  const { articles, categories } = convertToArticleList(data);

  return {
    props: {
      articles: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(articles)),
      categories: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories)),
    },
    revalidate: 30,
  };
};
```

Filtering articles in NextJS

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getServerSideProps` for any data fetching that is needed to be done at runtime. It's useful when you need to serve up-to-date information that changes frequently, like product information on an e-commerce site or user-specific data like a shopping cart. However, using getServerSideProps has a performance impact since the data is fetched every time a request is made to the server, which may slow down load times if the data changes frequently.

`getStaticProps` is a method used to fetch data at build time. This means that the data is fetched when the application is built and is then served statically. This method is useful when you need to fetch data that doesn't change frequently, and you want to serve the same data to all users.

Also, the `paginate(articles, currentPage, pageSize, selectedTag)` method you are calling, is a custom hook? If not then it would be better to convert it to a custom hook for data fetching at mount or if any dependency changes.

By combining `getServerSideProps` and `paginate` custom hook you can get the initial data and rendered the page on the server side and send it to the client and then on the client side on the page mount you can fetch the paginate data.